# Read Whatsapp message from Google Drive backup

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

I have WhatsApp backup file in my Google Drive account. How can I read WhatsApp messages on my laptop? I have tried it but can't be open on my Google account.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but there is no way to Access the WhatsApp or any other app backup in google drive only app can access their backup files we cannot access any file that is saved by any other application

But you can use WhatsApp web if there is any option for you